# Call function in controller from a nested directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two nested directives for building a treeview in Angular:

**Parent directive:**

```
myApp.directive('nodes', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            nodes: '='
        },
        template: "<ul><node ng-repeat='node in nodes' node='node'></node></ul>"

    }
});
```

**Child directive:**

```
myApp.directive('node', function($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                node: '='
            },
            template: "<li>{{node.ObjectName}}</li>",
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                if (angular.isArray(scope.node.Children)) {

                    element.append("<nodes nodes='node.Children'></nodes>");

                    $compile('<nodes nodes="node.Children"></nodes>')(scope, function(cloned, scope) {

                        element.append(cloned);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

**The controller:**

```
function myController($scope, DataService) {
        $scope.init = function() {

            DataService.getData(0, 0).then(function(data) {
                $scope.treeNodes = $.parseJSON(data.d);
            });
        }

        $scope.focusNode = function(prmNode) {
            console.log(prmNode);
        }

    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="testTree" ng-controller="myController">
        <div ng-init="init()">
            <nodes nodes='treeNodes'></nodes>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My question is how can I implement a click on the `<li>` which will call the "focusNode" function in the controller?

Comment: can you post html part?

Comment: @MaximShoustin, I add my HTML part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass in the function through an attribute.

**Javascript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('nodes', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            nodes: '=',
            clickFn: '&'
        },
        template: "<ul><node ng-repeat='node in nodes' node='node' click-fn='clickFn()'></node></ul>"
    }
});


myApp.directive('node', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            node: '=',
            clickFn: '&'
        },
        template: "<li><span ng-click='clickFn()(node)'>{{node.ObjectName}}</span></li>",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            if (angular.isArray(scope.node.Children)) {

                element.append("<nodes nodes='node.Children' click-fn='clickFn()'></nodes>");

                $compile('<nodes nodes="node.Children" click-fn="clickFn()"></nodes>')(scope, function(cloned, scope) {

                    element.append(cloned);
                });
            }
        }
    }
});

function myController($scope) {
  $scope.focusNode = function(prmNode) {
      console.log(prmNode);
  }

  $scope.root = {
    ObjectName: 'Root',
    Children:[{
      ObjectName: 'A',
      Children: [{
        ObjectName: 'B'
      }, {
        ObjectName: 'C'
      }]
    }]
  };
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.8" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.8/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="myController">
    <node node="root" click-fn="focusNode"></node>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: "Object #<Object> has no method 'on'". The error comes from this line: `<span ng-click="clickFn()(node)" class="ng-binding">`

Comment: Does this plunkr work for you?  http://plnkr.co/edit/XvqTfoullnXDVWRqFIyw?p=preview

Comment: It doesn't show an error but it doesn't write to console when I click on the span.

Comment: Weird.  What OS/browser are you using?  Works on my Mac Maverick and Windows Server 2008 R2 on Chrome.  http://i.imgur.com/YWJmQ6t.png

Comment: The error was gone after updating from jQuery 1.4.4 to 1.7+. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't comment until I get 50 rep cred :(...

I just wanted to add that I also got an error when trying the plunkr that W.L.Jared shared above. To fix the error, I changed the controller from a global function to:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', function($scope){...})
```

The error went away.

Good answer though :) Exactly what I was looking for.